# Cloud VPS requirements

Tags: vps, cloud

i'm planning to sign up for a VPS account to use for websites and SVN repos and similar. What i'm currently plans to host is:

> 2 Java Servlet webistes with low traffic (Tomcat/JBoss/GlassFish)
>
> A few SVN repos
>
> A Minecraft Server (Low traffic, but all traffic will be under a few hours)

Is then this VPS enough? http://www.server4you.com/vserver/vserver-details.php?products=0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should work (we used server4you before)

In any case, go with the monthly plan first so you can cancel if there are issues!